# How to acces mongodb collection through aggregate function (like group, count and distinct) through java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my mongdb Collection:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("50033fb1ecc250aa369a678a"), "ID" : 1, "FirstName" : "ijaz",
"LastName" : "alam", "Age" : 21, "Address" : "peshawer" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50033fc2ecc250aa369a678b"), "ID" : 2, "FirstName" : "ashfaq"
,"LastName" : "khan", "Age" : 1921, "Address" : "sadkabad" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50033fdeecc250aa369a678c"), "ID" : 3, "FirstName" : "danyal"
,"LastName" : "alam", "Age" : 18, "Address" : "lahore" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50033ff7ecc250aa369a678d"), "ID" : 43, "FirstName" : "shahzad"
, "LastName" : "sad", "Age" : 22, "Address" : "nazirabad" }
```

Now i want to use aggregate function like group,distinct and count on above collection through java driver or how to implement aggregate functions in  query through java driver.

Answer (score 3):

[Distinct](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#distinct%28java.lang.String%29) and [count](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#count%28%29) and special Mongo commands, you don't need to do any special aggregation to use those. Just call them with the appropriate parameters on you DBCollection instances.

```
myCollection.distinct("Age") // gives you all the ages in the collection
myCollection.count(new BasicDBObject("Age", 22)) // gives you a count of 22 year olds
```

For other aggregation operations, you want the Java `GroupCommand`:

```
new GroupCommand(myCollection,
             new BasicDBObject("Age ", true),
             null,
             new BasicDBObject("count", 0),
            "function(key,val){ val.count++;}", 
             null); //gives counts of each age in the collection
```

If you're running on the 2.1.x development release of Mongo or later, check out the aggregation framework. It's better than the existing group command (but not yet production ready at the time of this answer).

Comment: Thanx Alot Mrkut its so useful !